# Get Json from Web api and pass to partial view from controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

At the moment I have this as my code:

```
 public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
    {
        string url = "http://10.0.2.31/testwebapi/api/data";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.QueryString.Add("forename", model.Forename);
        wc.QueryString.Add("surname", model.Surname);
        wc.QueryString.Add("caseid", model.CaseId);
        wc.QueryString.Add("postcode", model.Postcode);
        wc.QueryString.Add("telephone", model.Telephone);
        wc.QueryString.Add("email", model.Email);
        wc.QueryString.Add("title", model.Title);

        var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);


        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/SearchResults.cshtml", responseString);

    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int Caseid { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        public string LoanPurpose { get; set; }
        public bool CourtesyCall { get; set; }
        public string isOpen { get; set; }
    }
```

im not sure where i am going wrong i want it to be able to pull that data from the web api (which returns a json file). then what i want to do is send that data through to my partialview where a `@foreach` statement will put it into a table but i cant seem to get it to send the data it is interperating it as a string and i dont know why

this is how it is returning:

[image]

```
@model  string
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach(var Case in Model)
{
    <p>@Case</p>
}
```

Partial view code.

This is what my partial now looks like:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Savvy_CRM_MVC.Models.RootObject>
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <p>@m</p>
}
```

which when i run through the for each is gives me this Savvy_CRM_MVC.Models.RootObject

Comment: What's the code for your partial view

Comment: @BurnsBA added it to the bottom for you

Comment: If you foreach iterate on a string (which is enumerable), you will evaluate each character.

Comment: how do i change this im very new to MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding you model to the raw JSON string.

you need to deserialize the JSON string to your RootObject class and use RootObject as the model for your view.

the following code user [Newtonsoft JSON.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize the string;

```
var rootObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(responseString);

return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/SearchResults.cshtml", rootObjects);
```

and you view changes

```
@model IEnumerable<RootObject>
```

You are also going to need to change you view to display the properties of your model.

Comment: Still underlined saying "the type or namespace of 'RootObject' could not be found

Comment: You need to fully qualify the RootObject name.  I don't know where you have defined it in your project.  I only know you defined it because you have it in your question.

Comment: RootObject is defined in that class which is DashboardContoller.cs

Comment: Move it into the /Models directory and reference it in your controller and your view.

Comment: I added a addition to my question because it still isnt working

Comment: Per my answer, you are iterating RootObject.  That will show you the ToString() of the object.  If you don't override it, then it shows the object type. You need to modify your view to actually show the properties of RootObject

Comment: how do i do this as i have been learning MVC for 2 days at work for an upcoming project and i have 0 experience with it

Comment: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview has multiple tutorials to walk you through learning different aspects of asp.net mvc.